# Google AppScript Import CSV as data in appscript

Tags: csv, google-apps-script

I want to import my csv as a 2d array within appscript, I don't want to export it to sheets, I just want to use the data to create google forms.
The csv is located on the google drive so I want to import from my google drive into a 2d array variable.

I tried multiple attempts of similar iterations of this.

```
function importCSVFromGoogleDrive() {
var slotadata = Utilities.parseCsv(DriveApp.getFilesByName("Slot A.csv").next())

}
```

To check if it is a 2d array I logged the `slotadata` and its length in the logger, but it returns as `[20-11-08 15:27:15:880 GMT][['Slot A.csv']]`

tl;dr how to import csv from drive into variable as 2d array on GAS (Google App Script)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`.next()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file-iterator#next) is simply returning the [File](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file), but you need to get the content within the file. (Remember that [`Utilities.parseCsv()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#parsecsvcsv) expects a string.) You can use [`getBlob()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getblob) and [`getDataAsString()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob.html#getdataasstring) to get that content.

```
function importCSVFromGoogleDrive() {
  var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName("Slot A.csv");
  var firstFile = files.next(); // If there's another file called "Slot A.csv", this may not be the correct file!
  var slotadata = Utilities.parseCsv(firstFile.getBlob().getDataAsString());
}
```